# How to extract a text table from Outlook email to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, powerbi, export-to-excel

I currently get a order failure emails that comes into my outlook inbox 100xs per day. The report shows failed orders, dealer codes, and names etc... What I'm trying to do is get that data exported to Excel so that I can run a report to see KPIs on different dealers.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a VBA script to achieve this.

Here's what I get in the email
[image: failure message]

and as you can see they are separated by spaces
[image: spaced error]

Ideally I would like to have the following info imported to Excel

any thoughts on the best tool or method for achieving this?
[image: final example]

I've tried to google and use various vba scripts like this and tweak it however that embedded table is what is giving me the hard time.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
Dim xExcel As Excel.Application
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xInspector As Inspector
Dim xItem As Object
Dim xMailItem As MailItem
Dim xDoc As Document
Dim xShell As Object
Dim xFilePath As String
On Error Resume Next
    Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set xFolder = xShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Folder:", 0, 0)
    If TypeName(xFolder) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
    Set xFolderItem = xFolder.Self
    xFilePath = xFolderItem.Path & "\"
    Set xItem = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    If xItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set xMailItem = xItem
    Set xInspector = xMailItem.GetInspector
    Set xDoc = xInspector.WordEditor
    xDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Copy
    xInspector.Close olDiscard
    Set xExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set xWb = xExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets.item(1)
    xExcel.Visible = False
    xWs.Activate
    xWs.Paste
    xWs.SaveAs xFilePath & "Email body.xlsx"
    xWb.Close True
    xExcel.Quit
    Set xWs = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I see you posted some code. What does your code do currently?

Comment: You may find the following helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377762/automatically-export-html-table-from-outlook-to-excel-w-vba